Inequality in Banach-Mazur Distance $d(X,Y)\leq d(X,Z)d(Z,Y)$
Let be $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ Banach spaces of the same dimension.
Let $d$ the Banach-Mazur distance and $\lVert \cdot\rVert$ the operator norm, defined in the space of linear and bounded transformations. Then
$$d(X,Y):=\inf\{~\lVert T\rVert~\lVert T^{-1}\rVert:~T:X\to Y \text{ isomorphism}\}$$
Or equally,
$$d(X,Y)=\inf\{~\lVert T^{-1}\rVert:~T:X\to Y\text{ isomorphism such }\lVert T\rVert=1 \}$$
I want to proof that:
$$d(X,Y)\leq d(X,Z)~d(Z,Y)$$
I think is enought if I proof the following contention:
$$\{\lVert (R\circ S)^{-1}\rVert:~S:X\to Z, R:Z\to Y\text{ isomorphisms such } \lVert S\rVert=\lVert R\rVert= 1 \}\subseteq \{~\lVert T^{-1}\rVert:~T:X\to Y\text{ isomorphism such }\lVert T\rVert=1 \}$$
and by properties of infimum, the inequality will be done. But I don't know hot to get that $\lVert R\circ S\rVert =1$,I just know that $\lVert R\circ S\rVert\leq 1$.
I would appreciate any help or advice

A slightly different approach to the one you wanted:
$$d(X,Y)\leq \Vert R\circ S\Vert \Vert (R\circ S)^{-1}\Vert\leq \Vert R\Vert \Vert S\Vert \Vert S^{-1}\Vert\Vert R^{-1}\Vert.$$
Now take the $\inf$ over all admissible $S,R$.

Ahhh, I see... Much easier with that way. Thank you so much !! :D
